# Getting rid of the double click effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/challenger/A5u43/11/). As you can see I've defined a simple *click* event handler:

```
$('#traveller > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $ul = $('#traveller ul');
    if($(this).hasClass('handle-next')) {
        if(Math.abs($ul.position().top - parentPadding) < totalHeight - itemHeight) {
            $ul.animate({top: '-=' + itemHeight});
        }
    }
    else {
        if($ul.position().top - parentPadding < 0) {
             $ul.animate({top: '+=' + itemHeight});
        }
    }
});
```

I've noticed that when I make few **double clicks** quickly, pressing `a.handle-next`/`a.handle-prev`, `ul` position changes unexpectedly.

Howcome I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fy59f/1/

Comment: Do you mean the problem is that if you double click it keeps sliding even if you reached the end/beginning of the list ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny this makes no change

Comment: You should set up a boolean animated flag. It is set to true when the click event is recorded, and set to false on the animation complete callback function. And you just check if it's false or true at the beginning of your handler, and only animate if it's false.

Comment: +1 to @RomainBraun. `finish()` won't fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check if `$ul` is animated:

```
if($ul.is(':animated')) return;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A5u43/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Check if an animation is occuring prior to executing the body of the event handler.

```
if(!$ul.is(":animated")){
    if($(this).hasClass('handle-next')) {
        if(Math.abs($ul.position().top - parentPadding) < totalHeight - itemHeight) {
            $ul.animate({top: '-=' + itemHeight});
        }
    }
    else {
        if($ul.position().top - parentPadding < 0) {
            $ul.animate({top: '+=' + itemHeight});
        }
    }
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/A5u43/19/

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock any action with your traveller, untill animation is finished. Here i used lock variable, but you can use any approach to lock it. For this purpose use callback on animate:

```
      $ul.animate({top: '-=' + itemHeight}, 400, 'swing', function(){
            lock = false;
        });
```

[Here is the jsfiddle like](http://jsfiddle.net/A5u43/15/)

Answer (score 0):

You could just prevent it with a $ul.stop(); just before you define who $ul is

here's the fiddle

```
var $ul = $('#traveller ul');
$ul.stop(true,true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A5u43/23/